# Extending classpath and Tomcat Plugin

Tags: java, maven, tomcat7

The project I am working at the moment is a standard web application and want to start it with embedded tomcat (mvn tomcat7:run). Within META-INF/context.xml there is an entry

```
<Loader className="org.apache.catalina.loader.VirtualWebappLoader"
        virtualClasspath="${home}/lib"/>
```

to extend the classpath of the web application.

When starting the web application with mvn tomcat7:run a lot of ClassNotFoundExceptions, e.g.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.deploy.ServletDef
```

are thrown.

Is there a way to get embedded tomcat with tomcat plugin to work while extending the classpath in context.xml?

Comment: Questions; do you have the classes reported as "ClassNotFound" within the virtual directory you point to? Is ${home} defined? Also, if you state just directory in virtualClasspath, the classes are expected to be found in exploded directory hierarchy; if you have several jar files within the ${home}/lib, you should list each jar as a separate virtualClasspath element.

Comment: The webapp works fine when running mvn tomcat7:run-war (and when I generate war file and copy it to an existing tomcat). The exception only occurs when using embedded tomcat. The classes which are not found are Catalina classes. {$home} is defined and I have exploded directory hierarchy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to this problem is to set the Tomcat plugin to use a separate class loader from maven.  This is done by setting the `useSeparateTomcatClassLoader` parameter to the plugin to true.  This can either be done in the Tomcat Plugin Configuration:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>
    <useSeparateTomcatClassLoader>true</useSeparateTomcatClassLoader>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

or on the command line used to start the Tomcat plugin:

```
mvn tomcat7:run -Dtomcat.useSeparateTomcatClassLoader=true
```

See: http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.1/tomcat7-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html